# Why is my Parent Window Cursor is set to Wait?

Tags: c#, .net, vsto

I have a simple VSTO application in which I am opening a Modal UserForm and performing some operation on Button click.
As, soon as the operation is completed, the Mouse pointer goes to Wait for a parent, however, when I move the cursor to Userform it's normal.

Can someone help, please?
Here is my code:

```
//Ribbon Button Click event

frmSortSheets frm = new frmSortSheets();
frm.ShowDialog();

// Button click event on Userform

 private void btnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    wb = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook as Excel.Workbook;
    Excel.Worksheet ws;
    int count = 1;

    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ScreenUpdating = false;
    foreach (var lstItem in lstChanged.Items)
    {
        ws = wb.Sheets[lstItem] as Excel.Worksheet;
        ws.Move(wb.Sheets[count]);
        count += 1;
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.Show()` instead of `.ShowDialog()` because a dialog will always make the mainForm wait similar to something like a Messagebox

Comment: Yes, it works with .Show(), however, I dont want users to interact with Excel when the Userform is open